# How use NeDB in nuxt project?

Tags: nuxt.js

I faced with this problem:

In server I have NeDB data file *pages.json* In serverside I wanna write some like this:

```
 const  datastore = require('nedb-promise')
 const db = datastore({ filename: './data/pages.json', autoload: true });
 const docs = await db.find({fruits: 'arbuz', a: {$lte: 10}})
```

*pages.json* awailable via HTTP, and in client side I wrote this:

```
 const db = new Nedb() // inmemory database
 $.get('/data/pages.json', resp => {
   const arr = resp.split('\n').filter(doc => !!doc).map(doc => JSON.parse(doc))
   db.insert(arr, (err, docs) => {
     console.log('all docs inserted')
   })  
   const docs = await db.find({fruits: 'arbuz', a: {$lte: 10}})
 })
```

In this way, I have *db* with same data on server and on client.

But I not understand how integrate it in Nuxt project. I know, nuxt have **nuxtServerInit** action in store. But it working only on server.

How I can make **db** object with same dataset in server and in client?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution!

In both cases, in server and browser I make inmemory NeDB database, load *pages.json*, and make bulk insert in db. I wrote a simple *nuxt plugin*:

```
 import datastore from 'nedb-promise'
 import axios from 'axios'

 const dbPages = new datastore()

 export default async ({ app }, inject) => {
   const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/data/pages.db'),
         arr = data.split('\n').filter(doc => !!doc).map(doc => JSON.parse(doc))
   await dbPages.insert(arr)
   app.dbPages = dbPages
 }
```

use this plugin is very simple:

```
   asyncData(context) {
     return context.app.dbPages.find({a: 5}).then(resp => {
       return {pages: resp}
     }).catch(err => console.log(err))
   }
```

I hope this solution is useful to someone.